# Select Top row in Oracle Sql Query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Hi I'm new to Oracle and unable to get the Top row using my query below

```
SELECT per.person_no, 
       perbus.person_no, 
       perbus.edit_dt, 
       perbus.org_name, 
       perbus.FIRST_NAME 
FROM users.persons per
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT ASSOC.edit_dt,PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_NO, 
               PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_ID AS PER_ID,
               PER.EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID AS EXT_PER_ID,
               PER_CONTACTS.LNAME||', '||PER_CONTACTS.FNAME AS NAME, 
               PER_CONTACTS.FNAME AS FIRST_NAME, 
               PER_CONTACTS.MNAME AS MIDDLE_NAME, 
               PER_CONTACTS.LNAME AS LAST_NAME,
               ORG.ORG_NAME AS ORG_NAME,
               T_ORG.ORG_ID AS ORG_ID,
               T_ORG.ORG_DISPLAY_ID AS EXT_ORG_ID,
               rownum AS rn
        FROM USERS.PER_CONTACTS PER_CONTACTS
            LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.PERSONS PER ON PER.PERSON_ID = PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.ASSOC ASSOC ON ASSOC.PERSON_ID = PER.PERSON_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.T_ORG T_ORG ON T_ORG.T_ORG_ID = ASSOC.T_ORG_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.ORG ORG ON ORG.ORG_ID = T_ORG.ORG_ID
        WHERE PER_CONTACTS.CONTACT_ROLE_LOV = 'EMPLOYEE' AND PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_NO IN (SELECT PERSON_NO FROM USERS.QA_APPROVED)
        ORDER BY ASSOC.edit_dt DESC
    ) 
    perbus ON perbus.PERSON_NO = PER.PERSON_NO and Rownum = 1
WHERE PER.PERSON_NO IN (SELECT PERSON_NO FROM USERS.QA_APPROVED)
```

I've tried using **rownum = 1** and **rownum < 2**, both however seem to have fetch two rows (image below). 
[image]

If you see I have John Doe same person with same person ID , but works for two different companies. I would only like my query to show the **latest** **edited** one which in this case is the **one** with **Google** record.
But for some reason the **rownum** is not working.

I also tried -

```
SELECT per.person_no, 
       perbus.person_no, 
       perbus.edit_dt, 
       perbus.org_name, 
       perbus.FIRST_NAME 
FROM users.persons per
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT ASSOC.edit_dt,PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_NO, 
               PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_ID AS PER_ID,
               PER.EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID AS EXT_PER_ID,
               PER_CONTACTS.LNAME||', '||PER_CONTACTS.FNAME AS NAME, 
               PER_CONTACTS.FNAME AS FIRST_NAME, 
               PER_CONTACTS.MNAME AS MIDDLE_NAME, 
               PER_CONTACTS.LNAME AS LAST_NAME,
               ORG.ORG_NAME AS ORG_NAME,
               T_ORG.ORG_ID AS ORG_ID,
               T_ORG.ORG_DISPLAY_ID AS EXT_ORG_ID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ASSOC.edit_dt DESC) AS  RN1,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_ID ORDER BY ASSOC.edit_dt DESC) RN2
        FROM USERS.PER_CONTACTS PER_CONTACTS
            LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.PERSONS PER ON PER.PERSON_ID = PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.ASSOC ASSOC ON ASSOC.PERSON_ID = PER.PERSON_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.T_ORG T_ORG ON T_ORG.T_ORG_ID = ASSOC.T_ORG_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.ORG ORG ON ORG.ORG_ID = T_ORG.ORG_ID
        WHERE PER_CONTACTS.CONTACT_ROLE_LOV = 'EMPLOYEE' AND PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_NO IN (SELECT PERSON_NO FROM USERS.QA_APPROVED)
        ORDER BY ASSOC.edit_dt DESC
    ) 
    perbus ON perbus.PERSON_NO = PER.PERSON_NO and rownum = 1
WHERE PER.PERSON_NO IN (SELECT PERSON_NO FROM USERS.QA_APPROVED)
```

Which would still give the output as below

[image]

I need to show the top row only but i get two rows as output.
I need to make sure the left outer join spits out a single row - any thoughts ?
i also tried maxdate option with no effect. Do you think i should consider CTE ?

Comment: you shouldnt post the same question in the same site (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34168550/get-only-top-row-from-sql-query/34171702?noredirect=1#comment56113733_34171702) if you arent getting a good answer.instead you should have edited your first post,

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this:

```
select rownum as rn, t.* from (SELECT per.person_no, 
   perbus.person_no, 
   perbus.edit_dt, 
   perbus.org_name, 
   perbus.FIRST_NAME 
FROM users.persons per
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ASSOC.edit_dt,PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_NO, 
           PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_ID AS PER_ID,
           PER.EXTERNAL_PERSON_ID AS EXT_PER_ID,
           PER_CONTACTS.LNAME||', '||PER_CONTACTS.FNAME AS NAME, 
           PER_CONTACTS.FNAME AS FIRST_NAME, 
           PER_CONTACTS.MNAME AS MIDDLE_NAME, 
           PER_CONTACTS.LNAME AS LAST_NAME,
           ORG.ORG_NAME AS ORG_NAME,
           T_ORG.ORG_ID AS ORG_ID,
           T_ORG.ORG_DISPLAY_ID AS EXT_ORG_ID,
           rownum AS rn
    FROM USERS.PER_CONTACTS PER_CONTACTS
        LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.PERSONS PER ON PER.PERSON_ID = PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.ASSOC ASSOC ON ASSOC.PERSON_ID = PER.PERSON_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.T_ORG T_ORG ON T_ORG.T_ORG_ID = ASSOC.T_ORG_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS.ORG ORG ON ORG.ORG_ID = T_ORG.ORG_ID
    WHERE PER_CONTACTS.CONTACT_ROLE_LOV = 'EMPLOYEE' AND PER_CONTACTS.PERSON_NO IN (SELECT PERSON_NO FROM USERS.QA_APPROVED)
    ORDER BY ASSOC.edit_dt DESC
) 
perbus ON perbus.PERSON_NO = PER.PERSON_NO
WHERE PER.PERSON_NO IN (SELECT PERSON_NO FROM USERS.QA_APPROVED)) t where rn <= 1
```

Comment: per my business i cannot use the rownum after the join to parent logic. i have to use it before or do something for the left outer join to spit out single row.

Comment: @Vivekakk I may offer another approach to you. Just move your code without rownum inside some VIEW, and then just select from that VIEW using rownum